# Will I lose my Clash of Clans account if I create another?

Tags: clash-of-clans

so I heard how to make more than one Clash of Clans account, and so I uninstalled the app, and I reinstalled it, and here's what showed up:

[image: Welcome image]

I have my account linked to Google, but will it actually delete my stuff if I create another account?

Comment: If you want to  use more than one account on the same device, use a [Supercell ID](https://www.allclash.com/supercell-id-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

This will just delete the fresh base you started with after reinstalling (level 1)  and load your base tied to your google account, which is listed in that picture as TH4.